# jQuery Hover and mouseenter/mouseleave not working

Tags: jquery

Simple query:

Iin the short code below with jsfiddle, the mouseleave does not get triggered everytime. I tried with hover but I face the same issue.

Any suggestions?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/wM8Q3/3/

CODE

GAME

INTRO

TUTORIAL

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    mainMenuLong=[];
    mainMenuShort=[];
mainMenuLong[0] = '<a href="#">Start playing the Game</a>';
mainMenuLong[1] = '<a href="#">Learn how to play Game</a>';
mainMenuLong[2] = '<a href="#">Learn to trade</a>';
mainMenuShort[0] = '<a href="#">GAME</a>';
mainMenuShort[1] = '<a href="#">INTRO</a>';
mainMenuShort[2] = '<a href="#">TUTORIAL</a>';
});
jQuery( "#navSY li" ).mouseenter(
  function() {
    jQuery(this).html(mainMenuLong[jQuery(this).parent().children().index(this)]);
  });
 jQuery( "#navSY li" ).mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery(this).html(mainMenuShort[jQuery(this).parent().children().index(this)]);
  });/*
jQuery( "#navSY li.fade" ).hover(function() {
  jQuery( this ).fadeOut( 1000 );
  jQuery( this ).fadeIn( 1500 );
});*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    mainMenuLong = [];
    mainMenuShort = [];
    mainMenuLong[0] = 'Start playing the Game';
    mainMenuLong[1] = 'Learn how to play Game';
    mainMenuLong[2] = 'Learn to trade';
    mainMenuShort[0] = 'GAME';
    mainMenuShort[1] = 'INTRO';
    mainMenuShort[2] = 'TUTORIAL';

    $("#navSY li a").hover(function () {
        $(this).html(mainMenuLong[$(this).parent().index()]);
    }, function () {
        $(this).html(mainMenuShort[$(this).parent().index()]);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wM8Q3/5/)

---

I will suggest you store text with anchor tag using attributes

```
<div style="margin-right:10px;">
    <ul id="navSY" class="introMenuSY">
        <li><a href="http://42charts.com/?page_id=828" data-enter-text="Start playing the Game" data-leave-text="GAME">GAME</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://42charts.com/?page_id=1716" data-enter-text="Learn how to play Game" data-leave-text="INTRO">INTRO</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://42charts.com/?page_id=1637" data-enter-text="Learn to trade" data-leave-text="TUTORIAL">TUTORIAL</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#navSY li a").hover(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).data('enter-text'));
    },  function () {
        $(this).html($(this).data('leave-text'));
    });
});
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/wM8Q3/7/)

Comment: Still there is issue with mouseleave. does not trigger everytime. But thanks for the neater code.

Comment: @user1517108, I have provided you different approach, that much cleaner

Comment: Wish I could give you more upvotes - you just turned my sloppy code into succint one - without my even asking for it - thanks.